# I can't use MEX function located in private folder

Tags: matlab, private, mex

I have a problem calling a function from MEX-file located in a private folder.

I installed the Piotr's Matlab Toolbox  (downloading and unzip)

I add this toolbox, including sub-directories, like this below:

```
addpath(genpath('piotr_toolbox'))
```

I can see a MEx-file `prior_toolbox/toolbox/channels/private/imResampleMex.mexw64`

My own `test.m` file calls this `imResampleMex` function like this:

```
B = imResampleMex(A, scale(1), scale(2), 1);
```

However, this produces the error message:

> 'imResampleMex' is not defined for 'uint8' inputs

I'll appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 1):

Functions in the private sub-directory can only be called from functions in the parent directory.

If you move your `test.m` file to the `prior_toolbox/toolbox/channels/` directory, it will work. The other option is to move the MEX-file to a directory that is directly in the MATLAB path (e.g. move it out of the `private` directory into the parent directory).

But the `imResampleMex` function is private for a reason, maybe you should not be calling it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I moved all the  mex files  to another folder and  and the function can be called now.